# Stop payment gateways overwriting referral sources on Google Analytics

Tags: php, paypal, google-analytics

So I'm having some trouble getting google to ignore payment gateways as referrers to the site.

I've added the urls to the Referral Exclusion List in Google Analytics and 
sent the return urls with a suffix of utm_nooverride=1 (similar to this question [How to exclude payment method as referral in Google Analytics, through code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31648105/how-to-exclude-payment-method-as-referral-in-google-analytics-through-code)), but google analytics is still starting a new session/overwriting the original referrer with the payment gateway url.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: The "trick" in the linked answer was not the parameter itself (that answer used utm_nooverride simply because that is how the feature was named in previous GA versions), but to set the referrer manually to your own domain and thus prevent a change in the marketing channel that restarts a session. It is not clear from your question if did the "set" call, too. The parameter by itself will do nothing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for getting back! I've set the referrer, and it's still not quite playing ball. I thought that, at the very least, adding specific gateway urls to the exclusion list would be enough - apparently not!

Comment: Do not at specific urls. Adding the hostname will suffice (i.e. example.com), adding a path  (i.e. example.com/pathtoexclude) will not work.

Comment: Also, the utm_nooverride=1 is for the older GA panel; the universal (latest) does not use that for referral exclusions. Like Eike said, for paypal all you have to do is add paypal.com to your list and it'll work. I've tested this several times and it works like a charm 8^)

Comment: Hey! Yes sorry this is late, all of the above advice was great and has worked like a charm. For some reason, GA didn't start ignoring addresses from the referral list straight away - but it's now working!